# REST - GET best practices for special characters

Tags: rest

We have REST API's. I was trying to figure out the best way to do a Get with some special characters.

Currently, we have something like this: http://myhost.com/api/book/name=HarryPotter

The above URL works just fine, but gets complicated when certain special character's are included in the queryparam like '&' or '/', which will result in "No operation matching request path ... is found, HTTP Method : GET, ContentType : */*, Accept : */*,"

for ex: http://myhost.com/api/book/name=Dark/Thirty.

This will consider the '/' in 'Dark/Thirty' as an URL separator.

What is the best practice to be able to search such queries. Is using a JSON a better practice, if yes should I be using a GET or a POST? I believe it should be POST, as any slash in the query param is treated as an Url separator.

Meaning: even this would fail for GET. http://myhost.com/api/book/search={"name"="Dark/Thirty"}

And since this is actually not a POST i do not want to use it. As I am just listing out the books that meet my search criteria and not modifying or adding anything.

Any guideline in tackling similar problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This link](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/) is a good read. In essence, if your `Dark/Thirty` is an identifier (i.e. uniquely identifies a resource), then modify it (in a predictable pattern) so that it does not have the special characters; e.g., `DarkThirty` or `dark-thirty`. If it is, however, a search term, then you would be better served *not* to make it RESTful, but just pass it as a normal parameter; that's what they're for.

The difference between `GET` and `POST` is not what characters are in it, but what the objective is. `GET` is for getting stuff: it should be free of side effects. A search, or retrieval of a page should be a `GET`. `POST` effects changes to a server. It is improbable you would need to make an operation that both requires sending more data than URL allows, and at the same time makes no changes on the server but simply renders a new page (allowing for exceptions like Shazam or TinEye).

Dealing with special characters in GET parameters is the job of URL encoding; if you have http://myhost.com/api/search?q=Dark%FThirty for a search, your site is no less good. There are two primary drivers for REST, as I understand them: human-friendliness and SEO-friendliness. Search does not need to be either. REST exists to identify resources, in my understanding; and search results from a query are not a resource.

To summarise, I'd go with:

- http://myhost.com/api/book/dark-thirty (the resource is the book)
- http://myhost.com/api/search?q=Dark%FThirty (the resource is the search procedure, with arguments)

Comment: Yup URL encoding is the way to go. This should be done as a default you don't even think of, solves so many issues.

Comment: If i had control over the book data entered i could go for friendlier names, as you said using of Dark-Thirty and assume there is an existing book inventory and the api lets the user filter or search the records using thr URL provide.

Comment: Your server should run the query string through a URL decoder anyway, as a matter of course. So it should be a bit of a non-issue. Most web frameworks do this for you for free.

Comment: You could also go with: http://myhost.com/api/book?name=Dark%FThirty as the URI identifying the book. RFC 3986 clarifies that the query component of a URI is not necessarily passed to the resource but may be used to identify the resource.

Comment: Also, the link you provided is misleading (see the comments in that post for an extended discussion). In short: there is no such thing as RESTful URI design, therefore statements like "[a search term] would be better served not to make it RESTful" don't really make sense.

Comment: @JonathanW: I view it a bit looser - not that URIs are inherently connected to REST, but that they have the form that has been promoted by recent famous applications and programming practices that implement REST. Just like when you say that, say, "Candi" is a "pornstar name" - there is nothing inherently pornstary in it, but it does have an association with sex industry because of the prominence of its usage as a sex worker pseudonym.

Comment: REST is not the same as "Candi." REST is a well-defined architectural style with specific constraints (5 required, 1 optional to be exact). It's my view that inexact or incorrect usage of a term which is well-defined (as REST is) generally only leads to further misunderstanding and abuse. And one might say that such apps which promote incorrect understanding of REST constraints are "infamous" rather than famous. :)

Comment: @JonathanW: I am simply saying that there is a sense under which "RESTful URL" is not nonsense, even if URLs are not specified under REST architectural requirements: it is URL that is commonly used in REST-compliant applications, which is pragmatically perfectly understandable. While precision is a good goal, there is something to be said for brevity, too. (See: Gricean conversational maxims, specifically Maxim of manner.)

Comment: It's used in both in REST-compliant and REST-violating architectures, probably more the latter than the former. Were the former more common, we probably wouldn't be having this conversation at all, as all client-server interaction would be link-driven (not URL-driven) and it wouldn't matter how you structure your URLs, as long as they identify a resource. So the point is: there isn't a REST best practice for special handling in URLs.

Comment: @JonathanW: No, but there is a popular practice called RESTful - which I suspect is what both the OP and the writer of the said article had in mind. I think it still makes it a better answer than "Your question is misguided and you have no idea what you're talking about."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41302/discussion-between-jonathan-w-and-amadan)

Comment: @Amadan The Link is now broken and returns a 404

Comment: @MikePone I used the same link the OP used. I believe it was just an example of the form of their URL, not an actual URL one could go and visit. The answer is about the form of the link, not about the content behind it. It would be better if OP used http://example.com/, which is reserved for such use.

Answer (score -1):

URL encoding sounds like the easiest thing to do in your case, particularly since you already have a URL structure set up for your application that looks like `http://myhost.com/api/book/name={internal-identifier}` where `internal-identifier` resolves to your book name (encoded, of course).

From the REST perspective, it doesn't particularly matter whether the URL represents a query that can return a collection of resource representations or uniquely identifies a specific resource. You can use this structure for both.